# Force Close "FATAL EXCEPTION" & "findViewById(com.google.…aterial.R.id.coordinator) must not be null" Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

I try to open new activity from bottomnavbar, but my app force close at first time when i open it, and this is the error message i get.

please someone help me,
and thanks for your help.

Error Code

> ```
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>     Process: com.apps.test.fx, PID: 24187
>     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.apps.test.fx/com.apps.test.fx.Dashboard}:
> ```
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException:
> findViewById(com.google.…aterial.R.id.coordinator) must not be null

Kotlin Code

```
private lateinit var chipNavigationBar: ChipNavigationBar
private lateinit var constraint: CoordinatorLayout


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard)


    val window = window
    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
    constraint = findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.coordinator)

    chipNavigationBar = findViewById(R.id.chip_app_bar)
    chipNavigationBar.setItemSelected(R.id.home, true)
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.root_layout, home_fragment()).commit()

    constraint.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.dk_purple))

    bottom_menu()}

    private fun bottom_menu() {
        chipNavigationBar.setOnItemSelectedListener({
            when(it){
                R.id.home ->{
                    constraint.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.dk_purple))
                    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.root_layout, home_fragment()).commit()
                }

                R.id.promo ->{
                    constraint.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.sft_purple))
                    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.root_layout, home_fragment()).commit()

                }

            }
        })
    }

fun floating_button(view: View){
    constraint.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.purple_500))
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.root_layout, home_fragment()).commit()

    chipNavigationBar.setItemSelected(R.id.home, true)

    val int = Intent(this, floating_action::class.java)
    startActivity(int)
}
```

XMLCode

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:onClick="floating_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:maxImageSize="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_app_bar"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_category" />

<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/dk_green"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView.Colored"
    app:fabCradleMargin="6dp"
    app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
    app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="50dp">

    <com.ismaeldivita.chipnavigation.ChipNavigationBar
        android:id="@+id/chip_app_bar"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:cnb_iconSize="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:cnb_menuResource="@menu/item_menu"
        app:cnb_unselectedColor="@color/white" />

</com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>
```

Comment: I understand that the problem is this view findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.coordinator) is null, so if you want to change your background, add an id in your ContraintLayout viewgroup and set this background

Answer (score 0):

Here's the error in your stacktrace (each error is caused by the one below, so the last one is the source of the problem):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: findViewById(com.google.…aterial.R.id.coordinator) must not be null
```

It's saying that `findViewById` call is returning null, when it's not allowed to be null. It's not allowed because you're assigning it to `constraint`, which is defined as a **non-null** type:

```
private lateinit var constraint: CoordinatorLayout
```

If null was allowed it would be `ConstraintLayout?` instead. `findViewById` returns null if it can't find a view with the provided ID in the view hierarchy you're doing the lookup on, i.e. the activity's layout you're inflating in `setContentView`.

---

So `R.layout.activity_dashboard` doesn't have a `CoordinatorLayout` (or any `View`) with an ID of `com.google.android.material.R.id.coordinator`. And looking at your XML, that's true! So you need to add one:

```
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/coordinator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
```

That gives you a resource ID of `R.id.coordinator`. Any layouts you're creating should have IDs in the `R.id.` namespace, not `android.anything.else.`:

```
constraint = findViewById(R.id.coordinator)
```

You should only need to access `android.R.id...` if you're using system-provided layouts like `android.R.layout.simple_list_item` (or whatever it is) or components like the standard app bar (where the home button has an `android.R.id.` ID)

Comment: oh right, I should have looked more carefully into my XML file..., looks like I need to go to sleep.. 
Thank you so much for your time and help...